# The last level of Arizona Sunshine crashes my game

Tags: steam, oculus-rift, arizona-sunshine

I have been playing Arizona Sunshine on my Oculus Rift, me and my friend were playing through with no problems at all. We finally get to the last level and just before I load into the game it crashes. I have tried to re-install the game and i have tried to verify it and it still crashes. I have also tried playing it single player but still no luck.

I have googled it and I cant seem to find anyone else with the same problem, anyone think of anything I could try?